# Triggering Maven Build on changes to particular directory in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We have Github repository with the structure as:

```
Project Name

- submoduleA
- submoduleB
- submoduleC
```

Every submodule is an extra microservice present inside the same branch. It is maven project. Every submodule is having a seperate jar which are not having any build dependencies.

I want to setup a Jenkins job which will get triggered when there is some changes to the submodule directory and build the respective jar.

Is there any way we can achieve that or is my approach is not correct? I also want to integrate Sonarqube analysis with it.

Comment: Make separate jobs in Jenkins...best would be multi branch pipelines and you are done...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you refer to these blogs to setup the automatic trigger process step by step, my favorite is the 3rd blog.

> 1. [Trigger Jenkins builds by pushing to Github](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github/)
> 2. [Automatically triggering a Jenkins build on Git commit](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html)
> 3. [Triggering a Jenkins build from a push to Github](https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae)